# Formula for item type in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, folder, item

In SharePoint, is there any formula to get item type (Folder or File)?

I have a calculated field on the list, which value is depend on if item is a Folder or not.

Comment: just an idea - will try to elaborate more later: you could discriminate based on the content type id? Given how SP handles the hierarchy of content types, it should be possible to use a "field value starts with" to see if the item content time derives from "Item" or "Folder".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible out of the box! calculated fields are based on the data and not the container type!

You either have to do it through custom code or through a workflow! or have an extra column that denotes whether it's a folder as bool yes else no and use the calculated field on that column

Comment: Yes, after tried many formula methods, I ended up with using an additional column to store is-folder flag.